# .NET Web API app OWIN authentication call to any path other than /token call returns index page instead of token

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need to change the token endpoint path for a legacy .NET Web API call from /token to /oauth/token. However, if I put anything other than "/token" in the **TokenEndpointPath** parameter, I get an HTML response (the index.cs page).

My **Startup.Auth.cs** is like this:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(InitContext);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<UserProvider>(UserProvider.Create);

            PublicClientId = "self";
            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
                Provider = new AuthProvider(PublicClientId),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(0.5),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            };

            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        }
```

I had a suspicion it is related to routing. This is my **Gobal.asax.cs** file:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     BundleConfig.RegisterScriptBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
     BundleConfig.RegisterStyleBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

     GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

     MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
}
```

My **Route.Config.cs** file:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Files/*"); //simos 

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Base", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Finally, my **WebApi.Config.cs** file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
     config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
     config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include;

     config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
     config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthHandler());

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "Signup",
         routeTemplate: "signup"
     );

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "Identity",
         routeTemplate: "register"
     );

     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
         name: "DefaultApiV1",
         routeTemplate: "v1/{controller}/{id}",
         defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );
}
```

I tried adding **routes.IgnoreRoute("oauth/token");**
in **RouteConfig.cs** to no avail.

Comment: It not solution, but where you call ConfigureAuth method? Set breakpoint inside ConfigureAuth and check it. Thx.